# WooCommerce - Place Order - Intercept functionality after validation but before processing order?

Tags: woocommerce

we have a use case where we need to issue one additional warning (in a pop up) to customers right before they finalize their order, but **after** all checkout field validations (form fields filled in, payment method fields validated, etc).

Essentially, we want the PLACE ORDER button to behave exactly like it already does (not clickable or working if anything fails validation or if there are any errors in fields or payment method fields).  Then, when it **clickable** and ready to place order, we want to be able to trigger our custom code (the popup) when PLACE ORDER button is clicked instead of actually processing the order.

We will then move or copy the default place order button functionality into our pop up that will work after they have read the warning in the pop up.

I am currently arguing with my developer who is claiming this is not possible because we use a Stripe payment plugin and she claims that Stripe plugin does not return the same validation error or hooks like regular Woocommerce so she can't check that we've passed Stripe validation on her new 'custom' PLACE ORDER button.

What I don't understand then and we are having the disconnect about is then how does the default WooCommerce PLACE ORDER button know not to function if there is an error in Stripe fields?

Shouldn't we be able to literally copy the PLACE ORDER code line by line and use it again (which is working properly and working / not working if there are Stripe or other form field errors), then intercept the last step before the actual 'processing' of payment and completing the order occurs to instead trigger our pop up?

There has to be a way to either duplicate the existing code and functionality and alter it to our means, or a built in hook/filter of some sort that validates ALL checkout fields (including from any payment method plugin) and show our button or have it function if all validation is met and hide the button or have it display "error" if anything is failing validation.

Thanks for any help on this!